# Insert multiple rows into table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using to using SQL Server. I'm trying to figure out how to insert multiple rows with one query.

In MySQL the query would be like this:

Code:

```
INSERT INTO Mytable (Name, Number) VALUES ('Joe', 18), ('Bob', 25), ('Mike', 7);
```

I tried a query like the one above in SQL Server and it gave me an error that said:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax will work in SQL 2008; in SQL 2005, you have to do SELECTs and UNIONs

```
INSERT INTO Mytable (Name, Number) 
SELECT 'Joe', 18
UNION ALL SELECT 'Bob', 25
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mike', 7
```

Comment: I'm glad you posted this, but to the makers of T-SQL:  Seriously, couldn't you come up with easier syntax than that!

Comment: Well, the VALUES(),() syntax will work in SQL 2008+, and since SQL 2005 is now a defunct product it all came out in the wash :)

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO sample (ID, Name)
    VALUES (001, 'happy'),
  (002, 'sunny'),
 (125, 'rajesh')
```